# PWA IOS Safari ServiceWorker is not enabled

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

Hi I've been trying to create a PWA and it works great on ANDROID but fails to function in iOS. I've got all the right functions except that later I've discovered that [BeforeInstallPromptEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent)  is not supported in Safari...
So I made sure that function is not run when on Safari.. but still it doesn't work. Is there something else that I have to do make PWA work in Safari. I think the issue is with service worker registration.

sw.js

```js
  
var cacheName = 'cachecard';
var filesToCache = [
  './',
  './index.html',
  './css/style.css',
  './js/main.js'
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
  self.skipWaiting();
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

index.html

```html
 <div id="installContainer" class="hidden" >
      <button id="butInstall" type="button">
        *INSTALL APP*
      </button>
 </div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
 // Initialize deferredPrompt for use later to show browser install prompt.
    let deferredPrompt;
    const divInstall = document.getElementById('installContainer');
    const butInstall = document.getElementById('butInstall');

if ( !(varUA.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || varUA.indexOf("ipod") > -1) ) {  
  window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
    console.log('', 'beforeinstallprompt', event);
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    window.deferredPrompt = event;
    // Remove the 'hidden' class from the install button container
    divInstall.classList.toggle('hidden', false);
  });   
}

butInstall.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  console.log('', 'butInstall-clicked');
  const promptEvent = window.deferredPrompt;
  if (!promptEvent) {
    // The deferred prompt isn't available.
    return;
  }
  // Show the install prompt.
  promptEvent.prompt();
  // Log the result
  const result = await promptEvent.userChoice;
  console.log('', 'userChoice', result);
  // Reset the deferred prompt variable, since
  // prompt() can only be called once.
  window.deferredPrompt = null;
  // Hide the install button.
  divInstall.classList.toggle('hidden', true);
  count=0;
});

window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (event) => {
  console.log('', 'appinstalled', event);
  // Clear the deferredPrompt so it can be garbage collected
  window.deferredPrompt = null;
});
</script>
```

main.js

```js
window.onload = () => {
 // 'use strict';
 console.log(navigator);
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js');
  }
}
```